# Can anyone explain this python static class variable case?

Tags: python

I have the following modules:

File `a.py`

```
class Foo(object):
  x = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print Foo.x #5
  Foo.x = 7
  print Foo.x #7
  b = __import__('b')
  print b.Bar.x #5
```

File `b.py`

```
from a import Foo

class Bar(Foo):
  pass
```

File `c.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import a
  print a.Foo.x #5
  a.Foo.x = 7
  print a.Foo.x #7
  b = __import__('b')
  print b.Bar.x #7
```

If I run a.py I get 5,7,5 and if I run b.py I get 5,7,7.  I'm not sure what the correct answer should be but I would expect the two to be consistent.

Comment: Sorry, missed an import line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python creates a separate namespace for the main module, `sys.modules['__main__']`. You test for this namespace in `a.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

However, when `b.py` uses `from a import Foo`, a *new* namespace is created, `sys.modules['a']`. **Both these namespaces have a separate copy of `Foo`**.

When you print `Foo.x`, you are printing `__main__.Foo.x`, while `b.Bar.x` refers to `a.Foo.x`, which is a different object.

For `c.py`, you are importing `Foo` from `a`, so both `b.Bar` and `c` refer to `a.Foo` there.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the complete explanation.  Also, you are correct, b.py starts with that line.